# Spaces between tags are ignored when rendering HTML to Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-html

Let’s say I have a function that receives a string that represents a text in HTML format and I want to show this text in Flutter. Some words in the text are supposed to be bold. If I have a few bold words in a row, the spaces between the  tags are ignored. How can I show the text without it ignoring spaces?

For example if I use this code and wrap the text with the Html widget:

```
Html(data: "<b>hello</b> <b>world</b>"),
```

It shows **helloworld** but I want it to show **hello world** .
(If I don’t wrap it in Html the spaces are printed but I do need to render Html to a Flutter widget)

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a non-breaking space entity (&nbsp;).
I don't know if it will work or not, but you should try this.

```
Html(data: "<b>hello</b>&nbsp;<b>world</b>"),
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I receive the text as a parameter and some of the words are bold, I don't know which ones. I wanted to check if there's a simple way to show it in Flutter, instead of going over it and adding spaces.

Comment: please clear your question's 1st line, I have some confusion with your question.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this line and it worked:

```
Html(data: text.replaceAll("</b> <b>", "</b>&nbsp;<b>")),
```

Comment: wow, great.
If you face any problem or any discussion about flutter, you can contact me on the linked https://www.linkedin.com/in/shawon-lodh/
Thank you.